# Alexa custom skill for a device without invocation name (not a smart home skill)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have created an Alexa *custom skill* that I am using to control various devices in my house. I am using a *custom skill* rather than implementing the smart home skills as I want to be able to support non-standard utterances. For instance, I can ask

```
Alexa, ask [invocation] what is the brightness of the porch lights right now?
```

Everything with the custom skill works really well, except that I don't want to have to say the invocation name. I'd prefer to interact with `porch lights` as if they were a discovered smart home skills device, like:

```
Alexa, what is the brightness of the porch lights right now?
```

This seems to be purpose of the `canFulfillIntent`. I have implemented this interface in Python (perhaps incorrectly), but Alexa always responds: "Sorry, I didn't find a device named porch lights".

Is what I am asking possible? And if it is, does anyone have a Python example? My reading is that while this is the purpose of `canFulfillIntent` it does not function like this yet (thus the reason why there are two ecobee skills, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Every time you ask for brightness and other things it will assume that you are referring to a smart home device and the skill will not be invoked. Thus the 2 ecobee skills. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQuMrfePbDQ) might help you if you go for a smart home skill.